# "onDownloadProgressChanged:" not being called (MKNetworkKit)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, mknetworkkit

I'm working on a project that requires downloading a list of users from a server —JSON data created from a PHP script that reads a MySQL database— and I would like to inform the user of the progress of the request but `onDownloadProgressChanged:` never gets called when sending a GET request through `operationWithPath:params:httpMethod:ssl:` and I don't know if that is an intended behavior or not.

```
MKNetworkOperation *op = [self operationWithPath:kSPGetUserListPath params:nil httpMethod:@"GET" ssl:YES];
```

Should `onDownloadProgressChanged:` be called when I send a GET request with `operationWithPath:params:httpMethod:ssl:` or is it only called when downloading a file using `addDownloadStream:`?

Whenever I send a POST request with a file attached through `addData:` method of `MKNetworkOperation` the `onUploadProgressChanged:` method get called accordingly.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because missed something like the following MKNetworkEngine initializing in the main class:

```
self.sampleDownloader = [[ExampleDownloader alloc] initWithHostName:nil customHeaderFields:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm currently initializing my MKNetworkEngine subclass in my App Delegate so thats not the problem…